# Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" on aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to upload function with an image cropper dependency as an aws lambda. It works perfectly on my local machine(`node v14.17.3`), but fails with the following error when triggering it as a lambda fn.

```
"errorType":
"Error"
"errorMessage":
"\nSomething went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module\n\nCannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js\n\nPossible solutions:\n- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp\"\n- Install for the current runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\"\n- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install"
"stack":
"Error: "
"Something went wrong installing the \"sharp\" module"
""
"Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'"
"Require stack:"
"- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js"
"- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js"
"- /var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js"
"- /var/task/index.js"
"- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js"
"- /var/runtime/index.js"
""
"Possible solutions:"
"- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: \"npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp\""
"- Install for the current runtime: \"npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp\""
"- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install"
"    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:30:9)"
"    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)"
"
```

The js file name is index.js and I have zipped all the files below. All the file permissions are as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 *****  staff     1379 Dec 26 12:22 index.js
-rw-r--r--   1 *****  staff      280 Dec 26 12:59 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   6 *****  staff      192 Dec 26 13:08 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 *****  staff    44154 Dec 26 13:31 package-lock.json
drwxr-xr-x  69 *****  staff     2208 Dec 26 13:31 node_modules
```

I am not sure how to debug this issue as per the suggestions suggested by the error as the image cropper works fine on my local machine. The image cropper version is:

```
"node_modules/sharp": {
  "version": "0.29.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sharp/-/sharp-0.29.3.tgz",
....
```

Any suggestions where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any update on this? Having the same issue

Comment: @55Cancri I did not find any clear answers for sometime, so I ended up writing the lambda in go. Unlike Node, go is statically compiled, so I needed to define the OS at the time of building the go executable. As, I developed the image cropper on a mac and wanted to run the lambda on linux, I have to give the go target OS. I think, the same might also hold for Node. Maybe, the generated node_modules need to be targeted for linux machine on which Lambda's generally run.

Comment: related: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2230

Answer (score 8):

To fix it on MAC, try this solution:

```
npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I had to do `npm uninstall sharp` first, because it wouldn't "update" the package without reinstalling it (yarn is fine though)

Comment: When using Mac, you can just `npm install sharp` and then `npm rebuild --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp` ( as stated in docs https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform ). I also added the rebuild command to a "predeploy" script, so that I am sure Linux binaries get included in Lambda code also when deployed by other collaborators.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using a layer, much easier to configure and deploy. On the AWS console, you can deploy this layer - https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:987481058235:applications/nodejs-sharp-lambda-layer

If that URL doesn't work, navigate to functions on the console -> Create Function -> Browse Serveless App Repo -> Search for "Sharp", select "nodejs-sharp-lambda-layer".

Deploy the layer -> On your lambda function, select the layer.

I currently have two layers, one for all my other node_modules (axios, etc.)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The issue will occur if any of the packages have a dependency on the Linux platform. In order to solve the issue, use the command below first which will remove the existing Sharp Package-

```
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
```

After that, Install the version of Sharp for the Linux platform using the command mentioned below-

```
npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=16x sharp
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Windows and want to upload a layer to lambda for using sharp
please use this command because I got the same error and got fixed by installing sharp with this command.
`npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=18x sharp`

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer here from another question..

The Sharp dependencies built in Linux and Windows environments are different.
Try building & creating the zip file in a linux environment. That should fix your issue.

[image: Windows & Linux node_modules for Sharp]

Answer (score 0):

Sharp has distinct builds tailored for each operating system. When developing on a Windows machine, Sharp will generate a build that is specific to the Windows OS. However, since Lambda runs on a Linux OS, you must create a build that is compatible with it.

If you force Docker bundling you are good to go.

```
bundling: {
  nodeModules: ['sharp'], 
  forceDockerBundling: true, // force docker bundling for sharp
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the Architecture you are using on AWS side:

`Lambda\Functions\YOUR FUNCTION NAME\Edit runtime settings`

[image]

If you are compiling from Mac M1, pass the Architecture parameter if selected "x86_64" architecture, i.e.

`npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp`